# Как можно реализовать функцию аналогичную встроенной функции Math.ceil

Tags: javascript

Для округления числа вверх без применения Math.ceil

```js
Math.ceil = function(number) {
  return number;
};
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
Math.ceil = function(number) {
  if (parseInt(number) != number) {
    return number > 0 ? parseInt(++number) : parseInt(number);
  } else {
    return number;
  }
};

alert(Math.ceil(6));
alert(Math.ceil(6.1));
alert(Math.ceil(-6));
alert(Math.ceil(-6.1));
alert(Math.ceil(-0.1));
```

Comment: для отрицательных чисел работает не так, как стандартный Math.ceil

Comment: @Grundy поправил

Comment: странное использование тернарного оператора:) `return number > 0 ? parseInt(++number) : parseInt(number);`

Comment: и теперь в принципе можно все в одну строку: `return parseInt(number) != number && number > 0 ? parseInt(++number) : parseInt(number);`. В принципе можно parseInt заменить на trunc, чтобы не приводить аргумент к строке и потом опять его парсить, но в принципе и так нормально :)

Comment: Я бы добавил что-то вроде `const inumber = number | 0` чтобы избавиться от постоянных вызовов `parseInt` (но это возможно вкусовщина)

Comment: Можно еще вместо parseInt() битовый оператор ~~ использовать, который отбрасывает дробную часть, правда не знаю что быстрее работает

Answer (score 2):

[Math.ceil()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) - Округляет аргумент до ближайшего большего целого.

Для отрицательных чисел это равносильно отбрасыванию дробной части, для положительных - если присутствует дробная часть, то нужно вернуть целую часть увеличенную на единицу.

Для отбрасывания дробной части можно воспользоваться методом [`Math.trunc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc)

В коде это может выглядеть так:

```js
function Ceil(number) {
  if (number < 0) return Math.trunc(number);
  
  var truncated = Math.trunc(number);
  
  if(truncated != number) return truncated + 1;
  
  return number;
};

console.log(Ceil(6));
console.log(Ceil(6.1));
console.log(Ceil(-6));
console.log(Ceil(-6.1));
console.log(Ceil(-0.1));
```

А так же можно воспользоваться тем, что `ceil` и `floor` взаимозаменяемый функции.

Так, [значение `ceil` то же самое](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-math.ceil), что и `-Math.floor(-x)`

```js
function Ceil(number) {
  return -Math.floor(-number)
};

console.log(Ceil(6));
console.log(Ceil(6.1));
console.log(Ceil(-6));
console.log(Ceil(-6.1));
console.log(Ceil(-0.1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отбросить дробную часть аналогично Math.floor(), можно схитрить:

```
1.5 >> 0 
// = 1
```

А вот с Math.ceil() придется хитрить многократно, преобразовывая типы:

```
x = 1.5;
(x >> 0) + !!(x % 1);
// = 2
```

Как видите - все возможно. Вопрос на сколько это быстрее Math.ceil().

Comment: Я бы сказал, что данный ответ **не имеет** права на жизнь: во-первых, он длиннее и непонятнее, чем `Math.ceil()`, во-вторых, работает с ошибками и не сильно отличается по скорости с `Math.ceil()` - [скрин](https://i.imgur.com/z2OgHwE.png)

Answer (score -1):

Вот так

```js
function mathCeil(number) {
  return Math.ceil(number)
}

console.log(mathCeil(33.3));
```

Вариант два

```js
function mathCeil(number) {
  if (!Number.isInteger(number)) {
    if (number < 0) {
      return parseInt(number);
    }
    return parseInt(++number);
  }

  return parseInt(number);
}

console.log(mathCeil(33.3));
console.log(mathCeil(-33.3));
console.log(mathCeil(33));
console.log(mathCeil(-33));
```

Comment: Надо без применения Math.ceil

Comment: Я в вопросе этого требования не заметил. Вопросы надо оформлять надлежащим образом. Тут не ясновидящие, а  программисты, общаются...

Comment: Вообще-то было очевидно, так как я переопределяю функцию в задаче

Comment: для отрицательных чисел работает не так, как стандартный Math.ceil

Comment: @Grundy,  не скрою, я об этом даже не подумал....  Буду у компа исправлю

Comment: Если передать целое число - оно тоже увеличится на единицу

Comment: @Grundy, Благодарю...

Comment: @Grundy, ответ имеет право на жизнь?))

Comment: у тебя условие `if (number < 0) {` ни на что не влияет: если оно выполняется `return parseInt(++number);` - а если не выполняется: `return parseInt(++number);` - найди 10 отличий :)

Comment: @Grundy, ну это я уже в математике ошибся))